# TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In set an Array into state in class component

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Navigation to get an array called `additional` using `this.props.route.params` when I navigate to a page, and when I render the screen I want to set the state details in the class component with the array additional, I'm still new to JavaScript and this is what I came up with:

**Array**

```
    Array [
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 1.01,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Ranch",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 1.02,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Blue Cheese",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
        ],
        "required": false,
        "type": "Sides",
      },
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 2.01,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Hot Sauce",
            "type": "Sauces",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 2.02,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Medium Sauce",
            "type": "Sauces",
          },
        ],
        "required": true,
        "type": "Sauces",
      },
    ]
```

**Screen**

```
class DisplayItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sides: [],
      details: [],
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { additional } = this.props.route.params;
    const { sides, details } = this.state;

    if (additional !== undefined) {
      sides.forEach((item) => {
        item['selected'] = false
      });
      additional.forEach((a, i) => {
        a["data"] = sides.filter(b => b.type == a.type);
      });
      this.setState((details) => {return [...details, additional]})
    }
```

I've attempted to use `()=>this.setState({details: additional})` but it returns only an empty array, then I've tried the above method and it returns the error: `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.`

Comment: Setting state like this could trigger a re-render which will end up with your component rendering over and over again despite no changes to props

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to spread an array `...details`, which is not possible.

Can you put debugger or console.log before `this.setState((details) => {return [...details, additional]})` and can you tell us what is in `additional`?

Btw in `()=>this.setState({details: additional})` you are trying to set `additional` which you probably assume is array, but it probably is just a string value.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to spread the whole state which is an object not the array part of it

Here you can destruct the **details** part from the current state before spreading it like this:

```
this.setState(({details}) => {return [...details, additional]})
```